# Error Code: 1136 when creating procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am crating procedure in mysql workbench where I want procedure to insert values in table, but when I try to call procedure it returns me error 'Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1'. I am somewhere overlooking something but I can not find it where.

```
DROP PROCEDURE usp_insertuser;

DELIMITER $
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_insertuser(first_name VARCHAR(45), last_name VARCHAR(100), date_of_birth DATE, email VARCHAR(250), username VARCHAR(45))
BEGIN
INSERT INTO user VALUES (null, first_name, last_name, date_of_birth, email, username);
END $
DELIMITER ;


CALL usp_insertuser('John', 'Smith', '1978-10-24', 'example@yahoo.com', 'johnsmith');
```

Comment: at first glance, you're inserting a null before `first_name`

Comment: Your `INSERT` statement doesn't have all the columns in the `user` table. Show the schema for the table.

Comment: @WimOmbelets That's presumably for the auto_increment ID field.

Comment: Show us schema for user table.

Comment: @Barmar yes, that was my second glance :)

Comment: yes, first column is auto_increment ID field, that is the reason why I put null

Comment: @Denis:- Then you can simply name the column which you want to insert as given in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the null when from the insert statement like this:

```
INSERT INTO user VALUES ( first_name, last_name, date_of_birth, email, username);
```

or rather make it as

```
INSERT INTO user (first_name, last_name, date_of_birth, email, username)
VALUES (first_name, last_name, date_of_birth, email, username);
```

Comment: Why should he do that? What if he has an auto_increment ID field there that he wants to fill in?

Comment: @Barmar:- Yeah that makes sense. Thanks for pointing it. Waiting for OP to respond else I will delete my answer.

Comment: thank you, I did take out the null out and then it worked, and when I look by selecting all from users table I notice that user_id was filled with number as it supposed to even if it is not added in procedure.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to list the columns you're inserting into explicitly. It's a bad idea IMHO to depend on the order of columns in the database schema. So do:

```
INSERT INTO user (first_name, last_name, date_of_birth, email, username)
    VALUES (first_name, last_name, date_of_birth, email, username);
```

Any columns you don't list will then be defaulted. When you don't provide a column list, you have to provide values for all the columns and you'll get an error if any are missing.